# How to Track Inventory for Bulk Product

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, inventory

I am interested in knowing if and how Magento could be used to sell bulk product that is pulled from a common inventory and sold in several discrete package sizes?

An example would be Potatoes. They are stored in bulk and packaged upon demand. They would be sold as 5lb, 25lb or 100lb packages. So the product would have 3 variations.

A key element of this question is that these are discrete variations. IE the customer will be able to order one or more of each of these particular variations.

Comment: Hello @BrianBurt , Please check my answer.

Comment: Hello Aditya, I realize this is a potential solution to ordering more product but it is not what I want to do. By way of another example we sell herbs. They are often packaged in different ways and different formats but they are pulled from a common pool. So I would have 30 gm. Clam shell, 30 gram bag, 140 gm bag, 1 kg bag.  The math in this case does not work evenly as the potato example does and infact the packaging is different. So if I want 10 30 gm. clam shells I need a count of 10 units not one package of 300 grams.

Comment: You gave me example of Potatoes. sold as 5lb, 25lb or 100lb packages

Comment: So i gave solutions according to that.

Answer (score 4):

> Potatoes sold as 5lb, 25lb or 100lb packages.

**Like you said set the actual product will be the one with the lowest weight.**

```
**(Potatoes 5lb)** 

This is qty = 1(or you can consider 1 qty = 1lb 
and set the product to be available for order only in increments of 5.)
```

- If the price for 25lb = 5 * price of 5lb ,
- the price for is 100lb = 4 * price of 25lb... and so on,

Then I think the problem is solved.

Selling **100lb** is the same as selling **4*25lb** even if you pack it differently.

```
If price for 100lb != 4 * price of 25lb, 
then you can use the tier prices.
Set a base price for 25lb (or 1lb if you considet 1qty = 1lb).
```

Then add the tier prices:

- for qty = 1 (or 25) price = X
- for qty = 4 (or 100) price = Y.

> In this approach you don't need bundle or configurable products.

**And Inventory Management**

There are two general approaches to the stock management in Magento 2. 
You can control all products’ **general inventory settings** or deal with each product **individually**.

> Stock Options.

[image]

**Decrease Stock When Order is Placed** – enable to decrease a stock quantity of the product when an order is placed.

**Set Items’ Status to be in Stock When Order is Cancelled** – enable to place items from cancelled orders back in stock.

**Display Out of Stock Products** – hide to display products that are out of stock.

**Only X left Threshold** – adds a phrase ‘Only X products left’ to all your products, where X is the entered number. Also, you can configure this for each individual product. Hence, it may be better to leave this option equal to 0.

**Display products availability in Stock on Storefront** – enable to display a stock availability on product pages.

> Product Stock Options.

[image]

**Manage Stock** – this option is enabled by default and used to count products in stock. It can be disabled if you sell products that can’t run out of stock.

**Backorders** – enable this option to allow customers place orders of out-of-stock products.

**Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart** – sets the maximum number of products that can be placed in shopping cart.

**Out-of-Stock Threshold** – you can set the minimum number of products to reach before the Out-of-Stock message should be displayed.

**Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart** – defines the minimum number of products required to place an order. You can set various limits for different groups of customers.

**Notify for Qty Below** – this option notifies you when the number of products in stock drops below the defined quantity.
Enable Qty Increments – allows you to set the quantity of a product in a single lot that you add to your stock.

**Automatically Return Credit Memo Item to Stock** – with this option enabled, products added to a cart automatically get an out-of-stock status and if they return back when an order is cancelled.

> Hope, it helps!! Let me know if you have any query.